# How to annotate a value from a related model in Django

Tags: python, django, annotate

I have a Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model, NiceTextPrintMixin):
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published",
                                    auto_now_add=True,
                                    db_index=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name="posts")
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
                              related_name="posts",
                              )
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/', blank=True, null=True)
```

and a Like model:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             blank=False,
                             null=False,
                             related_name="likes")

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             blank=False,
                             null=False,
                             related_name="likes")

    value = models.IntegerField()
```

What i need is to annotate a field to a Post queryset that would contain a 'value' value from a Like model where the post_id=corresponding post_id and user=request.user if such a record exists and 0 (None is also fine) if it doesn't. Is there a way to get that done in a simple annotate way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass arguments in @property.
You can implement method for Post:

```
def get_like_value(user):
    try:
        like = Like.objects.get(user = user, post = self,)
        return like.value
    catch Like.DoesNotExist:
        return 0
```

Comment: I wish i could use that but the problem is when i render the index page i have a single DB query that returns 20 posts. If i use a method like that in template i would end up with 21 DB queries instead, because i would need to run another query for each post on page. Which is what i am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField
posts_wth_like = Post.objects.all().annotate(count_like=Count(Case(When(likes__user=user, then=1),output_field=IntegerField(),)))
```

If user have like = 1 , else 0

Comment: It's too much complex, `Coalesce` do the job.